# Minimize distance using pandas dataframes and constraints (Knn)

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, statistics

I am trying to use for the first time Scipy and Scipy minimize. I have read the documentation and seen some YT tutorials, it seems everytime we need to minimize a variable we need to write a mathematical representation of the problem at hand.

In my case I have a toy example that represent my dataset. I have :

- a list of products
- a list of customers and a binary response on whether they bought the product or not
- a number of clusters I am trying to classify my customers with. The stored value represent the cluster's center, before the optimisation step it is set to 0.

What I am doing is pretty basic, for every cluster I am computing the square root of the square difference between each cluster value and the customer transactions. So that each customer have a distance value for each clusters.

Then I take for each customers the lowest distance value and sum them up.

- This total is the total distance I want to minimize, it's my objective
- The decision variables are all the 0s in the cluster,
- the constraints (Bound?), the clusters center should stay within 0.00 and 1.00

As I am using exp the function isn't linear thus I am using SLSQP, and my wild guess was to try out this :

```
sol = minimize(total_distance_to_minimize,   dataframe[clusters.keys()], method='SLSQP', Bounds=((0,1)), options={'disp'=True})
```

with the following Toy example :

```
#utf8
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize, Bounds
import math

#dict holoding distances between customers and clusters
distances = dict()

product_list = ['banana juice','pinnaple juice' ,
'maracudja',
'cupuacu',
'goava',
'coconut',
'apple',
'grappe',
'acai']

customer_dict = {'Bilbon Saquet' :[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0],
'Gandalft':[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
'Thorin':[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
'Smaug':[0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1],
'Radagast':[0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
'Elrond':[0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1],
'Balin':[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]}

clusters =  {'Clusters 1' :[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
'Clusters 2':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
'Clusters 3':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
'Clusters 4':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}

data = pd.DataFrame(customer_dict, index= product_list)
clusters = pd.DataFrame(clusters, index=product_list)

dataframe = pd.concat([data, clusters], axis='columns')

for k in clusters :
    for customer in customer_dict:
        distances.setdefault(customer, [])
        distances[customer].append(math.sqrt(((dataframe[k]-dataframe[customer])**2).sum()))

distances = pd.DataFrame(distances, index=clusters.keys())
total_distance_to_minimize = distances.min().sum()
```

May have I created to much different DataFrames in order for this to work ?

What would be the correct way of using Scipy.minimize to minimize that total distance ?

Comment: Solution other than Scipy are also more than welcome, as long as the distance gets minimize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the steps through which you can use the minimizer function in scipy for the problem.

The decision variables has to be a 1D array. Hence, I am flattening out your decision variables as

```
init_vars = np.zeros(len(product_list)*clusters.shape[1])
```

Objective function needs to be defined and that must be fed into the optimizer as a callable function.

```
def obj_fn(dec_vars):
    distances={}
    temp_clusters = pd.DataFrame(dec_vars.reshape((len(product_list),clusters.shape[1])),
                                 index=product_list,columns= clusters.columns)

    temp_df= pd.concat([data, temp_clusters], axis='columns')
    for k in clusters :
        for customer in customer_dict:
            distances.setdefault(customer, [])
            distances[customer].append(math.sqrt(((temp_df[k]-temp_df[customer])**2).sum()))

    distances = pd.DataFrame(distances, index=clusters.keys())
    return distances.min().sum()
```

Now, we have to set the bounds for each decision variable in a sequential fashion. Putting everything together, we will use the optimizer function as follows,

```
sol = minimize(obj_fn, init_vars , method='SLSQP', bounds=[(0,1) for _ in init_vars],tol =0,options={'maxiter':50,'eps':0.01})
```

For the given example, the optimal solution given by the solver is

> 5.562980209812645

The solution can be retrieved by

```
dec_vars = sol.x
temp_clusters = pd.DataFrame(dec_vars.reshape((len(product_list),clusters.shape[1])),
                             index=product_list,columns= clusters.columns)

temp_df= pd.concat([data, temp_clusters], axis='columns')
print(temp_df)
```

output:

```
                Balin  Bilbon Saquet  Elrond  Gandalft  Radagast  Smaug  \
banana juice        0              0       0         0         0      0   
pinnaple juice      0              1       0         0         1      0   
maracudja           0              0       0         0         1      1   
cupuacu             0              1       1         1         1      1   
goava               0              0       0         0         1      0   
coconut             1              1       1         0         1      1   
apple               0              0       1         0         0      0   
grappe              0              0       0         0         0      0   
acai                0              0       1         0         0      1   

                Thorin  Clusters 1    Clusters 2    Clusters 3    Clusters 4  
banana juice         1    0.685121  3.964158e-16  2.464523e-03  1.663972e-01  
pinnaple juice       1    1.000000  9.976724e-01  7.504636e-03  4.644470e-01  
maracudja            1    1.000000  9.972195e-01  7.066747e-01  1.774573e-01  
cupuacu              0    1.000000  9.959170e-01  9.999912e-01  5.891786e-01  
goava                0    0.993446  9.963349e-01  3.898192e-04  1.606294e-02  
coconut              0    1.000000  9.957576e-01  9.999994e-01  5.877336e-01  
apple                0    0.996145  1.676883e-16  2.963329e-01  2.001538e-02  
grappe               0    0.000000  2.918387e-16  2.711116e-18  1.562419e-17  
acai                 0    0.995514  1.584998e-16  9.947202e-01  1.472500e-02
```

Comment: Hey @AILearning,

thanks for your time, I think I conceptually understand what's the optimizer function is doing, it will feed the function with decision variables. The function will return the value and the optimizer will run util it reaches a minimum.

I have the following questions :
- is it doing it stepwise ? If so is there a way to set the step and the number of iterations ?
- is this a local/global minimum ?

Comment: yes, we can use the tol - for the termination criteria (which helps to drive to global minima) and  under options  we have maxiter, which will limit the computation time

Comment: What about the steps ? If we want the algo to try converging using let's say a 0.001 step ?

Comment: yes, its a ciritical parameter. use eps to change it.